# Efficient method to scrape each eBay listing

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape "Men's Watches" on eBay. I want my script to go on each listing and scrape everything (title, price, total amt sold). My plan is to make Selenium open each listing and scrape everything but that will be time consuming. Is there a more efficient method?

Video for clarity: https://streamable.com/uu3tt

Comment: Are you familiar with pandas and beautifulsoup? Those are my goto modules when I want to do web scraping with python and there are lots of guides online for integrating selenium with beautifulsoup! They may be what you need :)

Comment: btw, ebay has an [official API](https://developer.ebay.com/products/buy)

Comment: @Marat, I want to stay away from the API because I like to practice webscrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, to use another, more efficient way to get the data.

---

To grab the data over the website, I recommend you to

1. first create a list of all detail page urls
2. get the information from the detail pages as parallel tasks